# MembershipProvider not recognized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I'm writing my own membership provider (actually just extending the built-in one) and **MembershipProvider** stays red with an error that it cannot be resolved, even though I've added **System.Web.Security**:

```
public sealed class MRCMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
       //code here
}
```

Anyone got any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: have you tried a  clean build?

Comment: Just tried it and resolved nothing.

Comment: You do know that `MembershipProvider` is not the "built-in one", it's an abstract class with some basic stuff in it.  If you want to extend the built-in one, you need to derive from `SqlMembershipProvider`.

Comment: Are you missing the namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have added reference to the `System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll` assembly which is where this class is defined as stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx):

> **Namespace**: System.Web.Security
>
> **Assembly**: System.Web.ApplicationServices (in System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll)

Answer (score 0):

It works only when the namespace for the MVC application is present.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MvcApplication6
{
    public sealed class MRCMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I do have a namespace, I just didnt post it in my original post.